# Typed constant declaration list

Tags: enums, constants, go, iota

I wish to create an "enum-like" list of constants with the following properties:

1. The values of each identifier are sequential, with a few gaps. (I believe iota and the blank identifier help in this regard).
2. The identifiers are private to the module.
3. The constants can only be compared with other constants of the same type.

The enumeration is based on the [`enum fuse_opcode`](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse;a=blob;f=include/fuse_kernel.h;h=c7c99a5e0838611148ac88d4e714bfd9e89e1748;hb=HEAD#l250) from [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). Here's some code for what I'm trying to accomplish (and also very wrong):

```
const Opcode (
    _ = iota // skip 0
    lookupOp
    forgetOp
    getattrOp
    setattrOp
    readlinkOp
    symlinkOp // 6
    _ // skip 7
    mknodOp // 8
    // et cetera ad nauseam
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Go code for the FUSE opcodes. It was created from [enum fuse_opcode](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse;a=blob;f=include/fuse_kernel.h;h=c7c99a5e0838611148ac88d4e714bfd9e89e1748;hb=HEAD#l250). Typically you would write a script to do that; I used a text editor. Since the constant values match the C enum values, explicit values are used.

```
package fuse

type opCode int32

const (
    opLookup      = 1
    opForget      = 2
    opGetattr     = 3
    opSetattr     = 4
    opReadlink    = 5
    opSymlink     = 6
    opMknod       = 8
    opMkdir       = 9
    opUnlink      = 10
    opRmdir       = 11
    opRename      = 12
    opLink        = 13
    opOpen        = 14
    opRead        = 15
    opWrite       = 16
    opStatfs      = 17
    opRelease     = 18
    opFsync       = 20
    opSetxattr    = 21
    opGetxattr    = 22
    opListxattr   = 23
    opRemovexattr = 24
    opFlush       = 25
    opInit        = 26
    opOpendir     = 27
    opReaddir     = 28
    opReleasedir  = 29
    opFsyncdir    = 30
    opGetlk       = 31
    opSetlk       = 32
    opSetlkw      = 33
    opAccess      = 34
    opCreate      = 35
    opInterrupt   = 36
    opBmap        = 37
    opDestroy     = 38
    opIoctl       = 39
    opPoll        = 40
    opNotifyReply = 41
)
```

Comment: Please give a justification for why explicit values are best for an upvote. After trying all the options given, this method seems cleanest and simplest.

Comment: Why create an opCode type? How does Go know that opLookup is an opCode of value 1 and not a plain int?

Comment: I agree with @weberc2; shouldn't you need to declare that the identifiers in the const block are of type opCode? Otherwise you have to explicitly declare type anytime you initialize a var to one of those constants, and you lose out on other type features like methods on opCode.

Comment: @MattJoiner wrt "why explicit values are best" for *some* cases, such as where "constant values match the C enum values" (in which case the code should probably be generated via go generate like in the syscall package). Even if the values are 0, 1 2 (or whatever,) where `iota` is "easy" it's best to be explicit *if* you are following a spec/whatever that specifies explicit values (e.g. seek set/current/end). `iota` is best for when the values themselves don't really matter.

Answer (score 22):

You want something like this. You can still compare these constants against literal integers (there's no way to prevent that) but any comparison or assignment to other integer values will get a compiler error.

```
type opCode int

const (
    lookupOp opCode = iota+1
    forgetOp
    getattrOp
    setattrOp
    readlinkOp
    symlinkOp // 6
    _         // skip 7
    mknodOp   // 8
    // et cetera ad nauseam
)
```

If you really want to prevent external packages from seeing the fact that these are integer constants, but you still want it comparable, you might consider doing something like this,

```
type OpCode struct {
    code opCode
}
```

and only exposing OpCode in your API. I'd also suggest explicitly documenting that it's comparable.

Comment: Making the opCode be a struct means you can't use the const trick from above, or use the switch statement easily, etc.  +1 to keeping the opCode as an int.  Let a number be a number.

Comment: @RossLight numbers often carry different semantic meanings and it's often helpful to have the system prevent you from conflating them. It doesn't make a lot of sense to add DegreesC and BananaIDs, for instance.

Comment: There is no need for your `Eq` method. Go [defines struct types as comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) as long as their fields are comparable (i.e. just replace `op1.Eq(op2)` with `op1==op2`).

Comment: Yes - it didn't when I wrote the answer though! Will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

```
package fuse

type opCode int32

const (
    opLookup  opCode    = 1
    opForget  opCode    = 2
    opGetattr opCode    = 3
    opSetattr  opCode   = 4
    opReadlink opCode   = 5
    opSymlink  opCode   = 6
    opMknod   opCode    = 8
    opMkdir   opCode    = 9
    opUnlink   opCode   = 10
)
```

Comment: @Jessta: The extra layer of indirection does not enforce anything in the compiler afaict.

Comment: Why aren't you using `iota`? And why `int32`?

Comment: @Ross Light: What am I observing at the link endpoint? I tried the indirection suggestion and it did not work. I'll guess this is why @Jessta removed it from his answer.

Comment: I think it's because the "solution" he presented would still be cast-able to an int32.  The link I left was to show that the compiler then enforces that those constants are of the opCode type -- they can't be compared with int32s without a cast.

I just don't see why you *need* to enforce that the opcode not be compared with any other type.  Go's type system is designed to prevent you from making obvious mistakes, but it still has the "consenting adult" mentality of Python.  Just make opCode be an int.  Use == to compare.  It makes things simpler.

Comment: @RossLight Why have the compiler enforce anything at all? Let's all program in assembler. Hyperbole, I know, but I really don't understand why people think languages should prevent some human errors but not others...

Comment: If you read carefully, I agree with this answer, because it helps enforce that opCodes should only be compared with other opCodes.  I was mostly reacting (a year ago, I might add) to the other suggestions that the opcode be wrapped in a struct.  I'm not quite sure what you're getting defensive about, because I'm not suggesting that a strong type system isn't useful (Haskell is one of my favorite languages), I'm only suggesting that many newcomers to Go try to make classes and that they will come away disappointed.